# Hibernate 5.4 runtime bytecode enhancer enableLazyInitialization is not working

Tags: hibernate

I took as an example base Hibernate tutorial project ([Link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/hibernate-tutorials.zip)) > Native Bootstrapping > Annotations example.

Hibernate version: 5.4.29

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private UUID accountsPayableXrefId;

    @Lob
    @Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @LazyGroup( "lobs" )
    private Blob image;

    // getters and setters

}
```

In `hibernate.cfg.xml` I added following line

```
<property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization">true</property>
```

Unit test

```
public void testLazy() throws SerialException, SQLException {
    
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    
    byte[] bytes = "A byte array".getBytes();
    Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(bytes);
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName("John Doe");
    customer.setAccountsPayableXrefId(UUID.randomUUID());
    customer.setImage(blob);
    
    session.save( customer );
    
    Integer id = customer.getId();
    
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    
    Customer found = session.find(Customer.class, id);
    System.out.println("Customer: " + found.getAccountsPayableXrefId());
    System.out.println("Customer: " + found.getImage().length());

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

I am expecting that on entity fetch fields marked as `lazy` to not be even selected from DB, until referencing them explicitly, but I see in logs:

```
Hibernate: select customer0_.id as id1_0_0_, customer0_.accountsPayableXrefId as accounts2_0_0_, customer0_.image as image3_0_0_, customer0_.name as name4_0_0_ from Customer customer0_ where customer0_.id=?
```

Query gave same result (lazy = false)

```
List<Customer> result = session.createQuery( "from Customer" ).list();
for ( Customer c : result ) {
    System.out.println("Customer: " + c.getAccountsPayableXrefId());
    System.out.println("Customer: " + c.getImage().length());
}
```

In trace log there such lines

```
[2021-03-17 20:44:10.349][][DBG][org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column][main] Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Customer), mappingColumn=accountsPayableXrefId, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false} 
[2021-03-17 20:44:10.349][][DBG][org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder][main] MetadataSourceProcessor **property accountsPayableXrefId with lazy=true** 
...
[2021-03-17 20:44:10.351][][DBG][org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder][main] MetadataSourceProcessor property image with lazy=true 
...
[2021-03-17 20:44:10.461][][DBG][org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl][main] Instantiating session factory with properties: {... hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization=true} 
...
[... 20:44:11.382][][TRC][o.h.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener][main] Loading entity: [o.h.tutorial.annotations.Customer#1] 
[... 20:44:11.384][][TRC][o.h.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister][main] Fetching entity: [o.h.tutorial.annotations.Customer#1] 
[... 20:44:11.386][][DBG][o.h.SQL][main] select customer0_.id as id1_0_0_, customer0_.accountsPayableXrefId as accounts2_0_0_, customer0_.image as image3_0_0_, customer0_.name as name4_0_0_ from Customer customer0_ where customer0_.id=? 
[... 20:44:11.387][][TRC][o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder][main] binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1] 
[... 20:44:11.457][][TRC][o.h.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl][main] hydrating entity state 
[... 20:44:11.459][][TRC][o.h.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister][main] Hydrating entity: [o.h.tutorial.annotations.Customer#1] 
[... 20:44:11.460][][TRC][o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor][main] extracted value ([accounts2_0_0_] : [BINARY]) - [a897b3c2-c19c-4f36-b0a1-17bca893f433] 
[... 20:44:11.464][][TRC][o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor][main] extracted value ([image3_0_0_] : [BLOB]) - [{blob}] 
[... 20:44:11.465][][TRC][o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor][main] extracted value ([name4_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [John Doe] 
[... 20:44:11.466][][TRC][o.h.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader][main] Total objects hydrated: 1 
[... 20:44:11.467][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Resolving attributes for [o.h.tutorial.annotations.Customer#1] 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Processing attribute `accountsPayableXrefId` : value = a897b3c2-c19c-4f36-b0a1-17bca893f433 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Attribute (`accountsPayableXrefId`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Processing attribute `image` : value = blob0: X'412062797465206172726179' 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Attribute (`image`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Processing attribute `name` : value = John Doe 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Attribute (`name`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false 
[... 20:44:11.468][][DBG][o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad][main] Done materializing entity [o.h.tutorial.annotations.Customer#1]
```

So it looks like lazy-loading is not working for my example.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. What exactly hibernate version do you use from 5.4 branch? 2. Try to use query instead of direct fetch by id (session.find(Customer.class, id)). The behavior can be very different for these two cases.

Comment: @SternK, I've updated question - same result with query, but I expected that entity to be loaded lazily disregarding of query or `find`

Comment: The attached hibernate tutorial project does not contain the required maven plugin for bytecode enhancement in its pom.xml, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html for details.

Comment: @Michael in that doc it's specified that Hibernate supports both Run-time and Build-time enhancement ant they are (as I understood) independently.
Moreover, strange that for Hibernate 5.2 there is other parameter in doc `hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer`

Comment: Run-time enhancement is only supported in managed JPA environments and I assume that your project is no such environment. Have you tried the plugin?

Comment: @Michael
Yes, my application is simple maven project, not managed environment. With maven plugin it works as expected, but with runtime I didn't succeed: tried with Spring Boot Managed JPA Environment, but there are a lot of stuff to configure: TimeWeaver, ClassLoader - which is of my knowledge for now

Answer (score 1):

Try using "build-time enhancement of the domain model" instead of a runtime. It's simpler to setup and more efficient, since bytecode of the entity is changed during compilation:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    [...]
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <configuration>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>enhance</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    [...]
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After that in your entity class you can use `@Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )` annotation to lazy load column:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private UUID accountsPayableXrefId;

    @Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Blob image;

    // getters and setters
}
```

To verify, add SQL logging to your application.yaml file:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.show_sql: true
      hibernate.format_sql: true
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
```

and build your app using maven, since this plugin won't be invoked if you'll try to run it from IntelliJ or Eclipse:

```sh
./mvnw clean spring-boot:run
```